# Choosing a DB for a caching system

Tags: database, caching, selection

I am working on a financial database that I need to develop caching for. I have a MySQL database with a lot of raw, realtime data. This data is then provided over a HTTP API using Flask (Python).

Before the raw data is returned it is manipulated by my python code. This manipulation can involve a lot of data, therefore a caching system is in order.

1. The cached data never changes. For example, if someone queries for data for a time range of 2000-01-01 till now, the data will get manipulated, returned and stored in the cache as being the specifically manipulated data from 2000-01-01 till now. If the same manipulated data is queried again later, the cache will retrieve the values from 2000-01-01 till the last time it was queried, elimination the need for manipulation for that entire period. Then, it will manipulate the new data from that point till now, and add that to the cache too.
2. The data size shouldn't be enormous (under 5GB I would say at max).
3. I need to be able to retrieve from the cache using date ranges.

Which DB should I be looking it? MongoDB? Redis? CouchDB?

Thanks!

Comment: StackExchange uses Redis for their caching. It seems to do pretty well for them. However, I don't think they cache "all the things."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BigData solution for such a small data set seems like a waste and might still not yell the required latency. 
It seems like what you need is not one of the BigData solution like MongoDB or CouchDB but a distributed Caching (or In Memory Data Grid).

One of the leading solution which (which I'm one of its contributors) seems like a perfect match for you needs is XAP Elastic Caching.
For more details see: http://www.gigaspaces.com/datagrid

And you can find a post describing exactly this case on how you can use DataGrid to scale  MySQL: "Scaling MySQL" - http://www.gigaspaces.com/mysql

Comment: Redis provides a very simple limited Key/Value API with no real transaction support. While, XAP supports many standard APIs like JDBC(SQL), JPA(JPQL), JMS, Map, REST, Memcached and allows you to run Map-Reduce to allow fast data analyzing.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Gigaspaces in any way? You seem to be linking to it a lot lately, much as you used to link to Cloudify source all the time.

Comment: Why? DataGrid (or Distributed Caching) as I wrote is the right solution for his needs.

Comment: Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. Essentially: We don't tend to like people just coming here to hawk their wares.

Comment: I edited my comment. Read the end part. All you *seem* to do is post advertisements for products/websites you are related to. Offering support when people ask questions about your product is one thing. Selling your product as a solution is quite another.

Comment: I do answer on topics related to the product I work on  (since this is what I can help with). If you'll review all my questions/answers you'll notice that I'm also answering (as much as I can) on Java and STM.

Comment: @GuyKorland: If I see it correctly, you posted 16 answers here. Eight answers have been removed already, three others advertise products that you are associated with. This leaves 5 answers that don't count as self-promotion - not exactly a great ratio.

Comment: Folks, the OP and I have discussed things privately. Thanks for the flags, we'll take it from here :)